# Subshell, variables git and bash - how can I use subshell parameters with bach -c

Tags: bash, git

I'm trying to extract the revspec from our gerrit using this command:

```
git ls-remote | grep $(git name-rev --all | grep $(git branch --show-current) | awk '{print $1}') | awk '{print $2}'
```

Returning:

```
refs/changes/86/2214286/16
```

So far - so good (although, I guess there is a much nicer way to do this, please comment also if you have any idea how).

The general purpose was to put this command as an alias in gitconfig, this didn't worked as planned.

```
[alias]
    c = "git ls-remote | grep (git name-rev --all | grep (git branch --show-current) | awk '{print $1}') | awk '{print $2}'"
```

Outout this:

```
 git c                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 expansion of alias 'c' failed; 'git' is not a git command
```

I thought I can run this in zsh shell using "bash -c" (most of our team use ZSH)
But, it doesn't cooperate.

```
 bash -c "git ls-remote | grep (git name-rev --all | grep (git branch --show-current) | awk '{print $1}') | awk '{print $2}'"

bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `git'
bash: -c: line 0: `git ls-remote | grep (git name-rev --all | grep (git branch --show-current) | awk '{print }') | awk '{print }''
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Gili

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/60611612/9235408

Comment: Is your command correct? Shouldn't that be `git ls-remote | grep $(git name-rev ...` or am I missing something?

Comment: Correct (it works 0k in fish shell, bash, on the other hand - not)
Thanks!